# How to cite R packages when using Mendeley?

Tags: citations

In Mendeley, the closest category for an R package appears to be "*Computer Program*"; however, R itself is a computer program, not its packages.

Other literature sources seem to cite technical documents about R packages instead of the actual packages.

Aside from manually entering the citations, is there a way to incorporate R packages in my Mendeley library?

Comment: I think you could visit https://stats.stackexchange.com , or the famous https://stackoverflow.com .

Comment: Is the question here a) what is the correct way to cite an R package, b) what should I do to cite an R package when the citation function gives me a paper, or c) something about interfacing between Mendeley and R.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/8743/how-to-cite-software-in-latex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each R package has a different way to be cited. Some were formally published as scientific articles in journals, some only as packages. The only way to know for sure is to check how the package maintainer want you to cite their package, with function `citation`. 
Base R also comes with function `toBibtex` that help you export the correct citations as a bibtex file.

For instance:

```
> citation("Rcpp")

To cite Rcpp in publications use:

  Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois (2011). Rcpp: Seamless
  R and C++ Integration. Journal of Statistical Software,
  40(8), 1-18. URL http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i08/.

  Eddelbuettel, Dirk (2013) Seamless R and C++ Integration with
  Rcpp. Springer, New York. ISBN 978-1-4614-6867-7.

  Dirk Eddelbuettel and James Joseph Balamuta (2017). Extending
  R with C++: A Brief Introduction to Rcpp. PeerJ Preprints
  5:e3188v1. URL
  https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.3188v1.

To see these entries in BibTeX format, use 'print(<citation>,
bibtex=TRUE)', 'toBibtex(.)', or set
'options(citation.bibtex.max=999)'.

> toBibtex(citation("knitr"))
@Manual{,
  title = {knitr: A General-Purpose Package for Dynamic Report Generation in R},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  year = {2018},
  note = {R package version 1.20},
  url = {https://yihui.name/knitr/},
}

@Book{,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {https://yihui.name/knitr/},
}

@InCollection{,
  booktitle = {Implementing Reproducible Computational Research},
  editor = {Victoria Stodden and Friedrich Leisch and Roger D. Peng},
  title = {knitr: A Comprehensive Tool for Reproducible Research in {R}},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  year = {2014},
  note = {ISBN 978-1466561595},
  url = {http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781466561595},
}
```

As for importing bibtex files into Mendeley, I do not use Mendeley myself but [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383688/copy-bibtex-information-to-mendeley) on TeX.se shows that one can simply use menu items "File > Import... > Bibtex (*.bib) " to do so.

Comment: This is only a first step, to answer the question it would be helpful to explain how you get the output of the function into mendeley.

Comment: Yet another source for Bibtex entries which fails to escape titles correctly. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could export the citation as a bibtex file, e.g. https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/knitr/write_bib.html

Answer (score 1):

With the bibtex package, you can generate a Bibtex file from the package citations and then upload it in Mendeley or another reference manager software. As an example

```
library(bibtex)
write.bib('package name - here', file='name for the file')
write.bib(c('bibtex', 'utils', 'tools'), file='references') ## for multiple packages
```

Please see the package's cran page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibtex/) for further information

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, I believe you are looking for:

```
writeLines(toBibtex(citation("package")), con = 'path_to/reference_filename')
```

You can omit the package name for citing R. 
 Hope it saves someone a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
knitr::write_bib(c(.packages()), "packages.bib")
```

This will generate a .bib file containing all used packages, which you can add to Mendeley.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/write-bib.html

Answer (score -2):

For example, if I want to cite *Data* in *Function reference*
http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-data, in this case, I will use **web page** to added to Mendeley manually as follow:

- title = Data - Function reference - ggplot2
- url = http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-data
- Date access = 2018-02-12

Comment: I think that this is the wrong answer.